# How to parse hex dump

Tags: c, hexdump, flash-memory

I have a flash memory dump file that spits out addresses and data.
I want to parse the data so that it will tell me the valid tags
The '002F0900' column are the starting addresses. 
An example of a valid tag is "DC 08 00 06 00 00 07 26 01 25 05 09" where "DC 08" = tag number, "00 06" = tag data length, "00 00" = tag version. Tag data starts after the version and in this case would be "07 26 01 25 05 09" and the next tag would start "DC 33".

I'm able to print out the first tag up to the data length but I'm not sure how to print the data because I have to consider if the data will go onto the next line so I'd have to skip the address somehow.  Each line contains 58 columns.  Each address is 8 characters long plus a colon and 2 spaces until the next hex value starts.

I also will eventually have to consider when "DC" shows up in the address column.
If anyone could give some advice because I know how I'm doing this isn't the best way to do this.  I'm just trying to get it to work first.

The text file is thousands of lines that look like this:

```
002F0900:  09 FF DC 08 00 06 00 00 07 26 01 25 05 09 DC 33
002F0910:  00 07 00 00 1F A0 26 01 25 05 09 FF 9C 3E 00 08
002F0920:  00 01 07 DD 0A 0D 00 29 35 AD 9C 41 00 0A 00 01
002F0930:  07 DD 0A 0D 00 29 36 1C 1D 01 9C 40 00 02 00 01
002F0940:  01 00 9C 42 00 0A 00 01 07 DD 0A 0D 00 29 36 21
002F0950:  1D AD 9C 15 00 20 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 04 AD AE
002F0960:  C8 0B C0 8A 5B 52 01 00 00 00 00 00 FF 84 36 BA
002F0970:  4E 92 E4 16 28 86 75 C0 DC 10 00 05 00 00 00 00
002F0980:  00 00 01 FF DC 30 00 04 00 01 00 00 00 01 9C 41
```

Example output would be:

```
Tag Number: DC 08
Address: 002E0000    
Data Length: 06
Tag Data: 07 26 01 25 05 09
```

Source Code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
FILE *fp;

main()
{
    int i=0;
    char ch;
    char address[1024];
    char tag_number[5];
    char tag_length[4];
    int number_of_addresses = 0;
    long int length;

    fp = fopen(FILE_NAME,"rb");
    if(fp == NULL) {
        printf("error opening file");
    }
    else {
        printf("File opened\n");
        while(1){
            if((address[i]=fgetc(fp)) ==':')
                break;

            number_of_addresses++;
            i++;
        }

        printf("\nAddress:");
        for (i = 0; i < number_of_addresses;i++)
            printf("%c",address[i]);

        while((ch = fgetc(fp)) != 'D'){ //Search for valid tag
        }

        tag_number[0] = ch;
        if((ch = fgetc(fp)) == 'C')  //We have a valid TAG
        {
            tag_number[1] = ch;
            tag_number[2] = fgetc(fp);
            tag_number[3] = fgetc(fp);
            tag_number[4] = fgetc(fp);
        }

        printf("\nNumber:");
        for(i=0;i<5;i++)
            printf("%c",tag_number[i]);

        fgetc(fp);      //For space
        tag_length[0] = fgetc(fp);
        tag_length[1] = fgetc(fp);
        fgetc(fp);      //For space
        tag_length[2] = fgetc(fp);
        tag_length[3] = fgetc(fp);

        printf("\nLength:");

        for(i=0;i<4;i++)
            printf("%c",tag_length[i]);

        length = strtol(tag_length,&tag_length[4], 16);
        printf("\nThe decimal equilvant is: %ld",length);
        for (i = 0;i<165;i++)
            printf("\n%d:%c",i,fgetc(fp));
    }

    fclose(fp);
}
```

Update @ooga:The tags are written arbitrarily. If we also consider invalid tag in the logic then I should be able to figure out the rest if I spend some time.  Thanks

Comment: consider narrowing this question down, seems too broad as it is

Comment: If all you have is a text file hex-dump then why not first write a program to convert it back to binary form, which would be more straightforward for you to deal with. BTW, why are you opening a text file in binary mode?

Comment: Ooga: I'm not sure how converting to binary would help. I don't know why... opening in binary hasn't made a difference yet.

Comment: Converting to binary would get rid of the addresses and line breaks. It would also make reading the values more straightforward. Do you have the original binary file?

Comment: Also, it's simply pointless to open a text file in binary mode. That's why it's called a text file. Opening a text file in binary mode on windows causes the line breaks to be read as `\r\n` instead of a plain old `\n`. There may be other anomalies as well.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's binary but I have an original file that has no extension where I got rid of extra columns and saved it as ".txt".  I do need to be able to print the addresses for the corresponding tags though, would I be able to do that if I have a binary file?

Comment: Since we're not sure, we'll just work with the text file. I'll get back to you....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just an idea to get you started since I'm not entirely sure what you need. The basic idea is that `read_byte` returns the next two-digit hex value as a byte and also returns its address.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define FILE_NAME "UA201_dump.txt"

void err(char *msg) {
  fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s\n", msg);
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

// read_byte
// Reads a single two-digit "byte" from the hex dump, also
// reads the address (if necessary).
// Returns the byte and current address through pointers.
// Returns 1 if it was able to read a byte, 0 otherwise.

int read_byte(FILE *fp, unsigned *byte, unsigned *addr_ret) {

  // Save current column and address between calls.
  static int column = 0;
  static unsigned addr;

  // If it's the beginning of a line...
  if (column == 0)
    // ... read the address.
    if (fscanf(fp, "%x:", &addr) != 1)
      // Return 0 if no address could be read.
      return 0;

  // Read the next two-digit hex value into *byte.
  if (fscanf(fp, "%x", byte) != 1)
    // Return 0 if no byte could be read.
    return 0;

  // Set return address to current address.
  *addr_ret = addr;
  // Increment current address for next time.
  ++addr;

  // Increment column, wrapping back to 0 when it reaches 16.
  column = (column + 1) % 16;

  // Return 1 on success.
  return 1;
}


int main() {
  unsigned byte, addr, afterdc, length, version, i;

  FILE *fp = fopen(FILE_NAME,"r");
  if (!fp) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Can't open %s\n", FILE_NAME);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  while (read_byte(fp, &byte, &addr)) {
    if (byte == 0xDC) {

      // Read additional bytes like this:
      if (!read_byte(fp, &afterdc, &addr)) err("EOF 1");

      if (!read_byte(fp, &length, &addr)) err("EOF 2");
      if (!read_byte(fp, &byte, &addr)) err("EOF 3");
      length = (length << 8) | byte;

      if (!read_byte(fp, &version, &addr)) err("EOF 4");
      if (!read_byte(fp, &byte, &addr)) err("EOF 5");
      version = (version << 8) | byte;

      printf("DC: %02X, %u, %u\n  ", afterdc, length, version);
      for (i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        if (!read_byte(fp, &byte, &addr)) err("EOF 6");
        printf("%02X ", byte);
      }
      putchar('\n');
    }
  }

  fclose(fp);
  return 0;
}
```

Some explanation:

Every time `read_byte` is called, it reads the next printed byte (the two-digit hex values) from the hex dump. It returns that byte and also the address of that byte.

There are 16 two-digit hex values on each line. The column number (0 to 15) is retained in a static variable between calls. The column is incremented after reading each byte and reset to 0 every time the column reaches 16.

Any time the column number is 0, it reads the printed address, retaining it between calls in a static variable. It also increments the static addr variable so it can tell you the address of a byte anywhere in the line (when the column number is not zero).

As an example, you could use `read_bye` like this, which prints each byte value and it's address on a separate line:

```
// after opening file as fp
while (read_byte(fp, &byte, &addr))
    printf("%08X- %02X\n", addr, byte);
```

(Not that it would be useful to do that, but to test it you could run it with the snippet you provided in your question.)

Comment: Thanks, I'm a bit confused what you mean by consecutive bytes and their addresses.  For example, what does the first read_byte(fp, &afterdc, &addr) do?

Comment: Ooga: Wow! I will try to configure it to what I need it to show.  How does it know/store the addresss(002F0900)/How are you only reading the 16 columns for hex values?

Comment: @user2946437 That's probably a little too much to explain here! Sounds like you need a book on C. Most of the *magic* is from `fscanf`, which (using the `%x` format spec) reads a hex value from a text file. `static` means that the value of the variable will be remembered between function calls. Also note that `read_byte` returns 0 if it encounters the end of the file (or some other problem), and returns 1 otherwise. I'll add some comments to the function.

Comment: I see it now....  Is there a way to tell it to read in "length" bytes after the version.  Right now, if there is a "DC" byte in the data. read_byte reads DC and start a new tag even though the other "DC" is part of the data.

Comment: @user2946437 `read_byte` just returns consecutive bytes, not caring what the value is. The rest of the logic is up to you. I can only help you further if you can better describe (by editing your question) exactly what you're trying to do (I don't totally understand). The `main` above reads bytes until it finds 0xDC, then it reads the next byte (saving it as `afterdc`), then it reads the next two (saving them as `length`), then it reads the next two (saving them as `version`), and then it reads `length` additional bytes (whether they are 0xDC or not). Then it starts looking for 0xDC again.

Comment: Let me figure it out first what is actually happening and try the logic of what I want(We're very close) and I'll get back to you. Thanks